# type <> must implement AsyncTask<> doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am getting error in below code saying that i must implement atleast one inherited method of AsyncTask class but i am implementing 3 of them still it raising error. do anyone see any issue in this code

```
List<NameValuePair> login_details = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
new CheckUserValidation().execute(login_details);

class CheckUserValidation extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(RrdMainActivity.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Validating user...");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> args;
        args=params[0];
        http_resp = httpparser.makeHttpRequest(url_validate_user, "GET", args);

        try
        {
            int success_code = http_resp.getInt(TagSuccess);
            if(success_code == 1)
            {
                return "valid";
            }
            else
            {
                return "invalid";
            }

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "valid";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String success_message){

        if (success_message == "valid")
        {
            pdialog.dismiss();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("imessage", http_resp.toString());

            Intent i = new Intent(RrdMainActivity.this,AllClasses.class);
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            pdialog.setMessage("Invalid userid/password. please try again...");
            pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are not overriding anything :)

Comment: @jvrodrigues i thought overriding onpreexecute would do the play... :D i added it in doInBackground now..

Comment: To avoid this kind of errors i highly advise using a good android IDE like android-studio which as already reached a point where it's simply better than eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair> params) {
```

to:

```
protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
```

and add:

```
@Override
```

Comment: changing the arguments to (List<NameValuePair>... params) clears the error on asynctask class but throws when i make call to hpptparser class. in the httpparser class i am expacting below arguments """""public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params)"""" does adding the "..." in the argument makes it an array ? how to deal with it ?

Comment: @PawanRawat use `params[0]` instead of `params` as argument for `makeHttpRequest`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 
@Override
before your doInBackground function

Answer (score 0):

You should override your doInBbackground method, like this

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair> params)
```

Also, I would recommend making your life easier by using this library for background works
https://github.com/Arasthel/AsyncJobLibrary

its this simple..

```
AsyncJob.doInBackground(new AsyncJob.OnBackgroundJob() {

    @Override
    public void doOnBackground() {
        startRecording();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks KC for the link :)

Comment: your simple example could be a simple `new Thread(Runnable)` as well, - or `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {/* run() */})`